# Solving Linear Algebraic Equation: $x+y+z=xyz$

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving

I am solving an algebraic equation: $x+y+z=xyz$ for $x, y,z\in\mathbb{N}$
I want to find out what $x, y, z$ are and if  there are more possibilities.
By guessing I found out that $x,y,z=1,2,3$ but I want to solve it solve it algebraically.
I solved the Equation for $x$:
$$
x+y+z=xyz
$$
$$
\text{Subtract } xyz
$$
$$
x+y+z-xyz=0
$$
$$
\text{Add }{-y-z}
$$
$$
x-xyz=-y-z
$$
$$
\text{Factor out }x
$$
$$
x(-yz+1)=-y-z
$$
$$
\text{Divide by }{-yz+1}
$$
$$
\frac{x(-yz+1)}{-yz+1}=\frac{-y-z}{-yz+1}
$$
$$
x=\frac{-y-z}{-yz+1}
$$
$$
\text{Take Factor as }{-1}
$$
$$
x=\frac{-1(-y-z)}{-1(-yz+1)}
$$
$$
x=\frac{y+z}{yz-1}
$$
But I can't go any further by replacing $x$:
$$
\frac{y+z}{yz-1}+y+z=\left(\frac{y+z}{yz-1}\right)yz
$$
Can please you help me?

Comment: You won't be able to "solve" this equation since there is no unique solution. Instead, note that if $xy\neq1$, then $$z=\frac{x+y}{xy-1}$$satisfies the equation. There are no other solutions, since if $xy=1$, then $x+y=0$, and that is clearly not possible to satisfy in the reals.

Comment: You need to specify what the values of $x,y,z$ are allowed to be. For example do you mean them to be positive integers? Or rationals? Or reals? Also do you want them all different?